# how to find two expressions equivalent after transformation (e.g. commutative law etc.)

Tags: python, math, operators, sympy

I am making a 24-point game for my cousin and the program I design is to output all the possible solutions for the given four or five numbers. The underlying mechanism is basically finding all the possible bracket positions and fit in numbers to see whether the result is 24.
The program is now able to find all answers but there is one big problem.

For example, given the numbers

3,3,6,7,9

one possible answer is

3*((9+7)/6*3)

However, the program will also give answers like

3*(9+7)/(6/3)

3*((9+7)/(6/3))

These are actually equivalent equations and should not be considered as different answers. I have managed to eliminate some of the equivalent answers by removing all the answers containing '+(', '-(', ')-', ')+' and ')*'. Is there any way to eliminate all the equivalent expressions? Thank you!

I have attached my current code below.

```
from itertools import permutations

while True:
    numnum = input('Please choose number of cards (enter anything other than 4 and 5 to quit the program):')
    if numnum == '4':
        try:
            a = int(input("Please enter the first number:"))
            b = int(input("Please enter the second number:"))
            c = int(input("Please enter the third number:"))
            d = int(input("Please enter the fourth number:"))
        except:
            print('WARNING: Please enter a real number!')
            continue

        print('Processing...')
        my_list = [a, b, c, d]
        # Randomly arrange a list of 4 integers
        result = [c for c in permutations(my_list, 4)]

        symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

        list2 = []  # Calculate the list of 24 permutations and combinations

        flag = False

        for one, two, three, four in result:
            for s1 in symbols:
                for s2 in symbols:
                    for s3 in symbols:
                        if s1 + s2 + s3 in ['+++', '***', '+--', '++-', '**/', '*//', '///']:
                            express = ["{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four)]
                        elif s1 + s2 + s3 in ['+-+', '-++', '-+-', '--+', '*/*', '/**', '/*/', '//*']:
                            continue
                        else:
                            express = ["({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}{5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}){5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}{6})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "{0}{1}{2}{3}({4}{5}{6})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "(({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}){5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "({0}{1}{2}){3}({4}{5}{6})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "({0}{1}({2}{3}{4})){5}{6}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "{0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}){5}{6})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four),
                                       "{0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}{6}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four)]

                        for e in express:
                            try:
                                if eval(e) == 24:
                                    list2.append(e)
                                    flag = True
                            except ZeroDivisionError:
                                pass

        for c in list2:
            if '+(' in c or '-(' in c or ')-' in c or ')+' in c or ')*' in c:
                continue
            print(c)

        if not flag:
            print("NO solution...")

    elif numnum == '5':
        try:
            a = int(input("Please enter the first number:"))
            b = int(input("Please enter the second number:"))
            c = int(input("Please enter the third number:"))
            d = int(input("Please enter the fourth number:"))
            e = int(input('Please enter the fifth number:'))
        except:
            print('WARNING: Please enter a real number!')
            continue

        print('Processing...')
        my_list = [a, b, c, d, e]
        # Randomly arrange a list of 4 integers
        result = [c for c in permutations(my_list, 5)]

        symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

        list2 = []  # Calculate the list of 24 permutations and combinations

        flag = False

        for one, two, three, four, five in result:
            for s1 in symbols:
                for s2 in symbols:
                    for s3 in symbols:
                        for s4 in symbols:
                            if s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 in ['++++', '****', '+---', '+++-', '++--', '**//', '*///', '///',
                                                     '***/']:
                                express = ["{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five)]
                            elif (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['*', '/', '/', '/']) \
                                    or (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['*', '*', '/', '/']) \
                                    or (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['*', '*', '*', '/']) \
                                    or (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['+', '-', '-', '-']) \
                                    or (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['+', '+', '-', '-']) \
                                    or (s1, s2, s3, s4) in permutations(['+', '+', '+', '-']):
                                continue
                            else:
                                express = ["({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}){5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}{2}{3}({4}{5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}{2}{3}({4}{5}{6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}({6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "(({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}){5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "(({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}{5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}){3}({4}{5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}){3}({4}{5}{6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}{5}({6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}){5}({6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "(({0}{1}{2}{3}{4}){5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}({2}{3}{4})){5}{6}{7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}{3}({4}{5}{6})){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}{6})){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}){5}({6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}{6})){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}{5}{6}){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}{6}){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}{6}{7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}{4}{5}({6}{7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}{2}{3}(({4}{5}{6}){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}{2}{3}({4}{5}({6}{7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "((({0}{1}{2}){3}{4}){5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "(({0}{1}{2}){3}({4}{5}{6})){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}){3}(({4}{5}{6}){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}{2}){3}({4}{5}({6}{7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "(({0}{1}({2}{3}{4})){5}{6}){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}({2}{3}{4})){5}({6}{7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}){5}{6})){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "({0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}{6}))){7}{8}".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}((({2}{3}{4}){5}{6}){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}(({2}{3}{4}){5}({6}{7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}(({2}{3}({4}{5}{6})){7}{8})".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}(({4}{5}{6}){7}{8}))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five),
                                           "{0}{1}({2}{3}({4}{5}({6}{7}{8})))".format(one, s1, two, s2, three, s3, four, s4, five)]

                            for e in express:
                                try:
                                    if eval(e) == 24:
                                        list2.append(e)
                                        flag = True
                                except ZeroDivisionError:
                                    pass

        for c in list2:
            if '+(' in c or '-(' in c or ')-' in c or ')+' in c or ')*' in c:
                continue
            print(c)

        if not flag:
            print("NO solution...")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: What are the rules for equivalence? At the highest level, all expressions generated are equivalent, since they all calculate to 24. And compared to your first example, is `3*3*((9+7)/6)` equivalent? Or `3*3*(9+7)/6`? I was thinking that if the expression lists the numbers in the same sequence, and yields the same result, it would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `eval()`?

```
for i, e1 in sorted(enumerate(express), reverse=True): # reversed and enumerate so we can remove during iteration by popping an index
    for n, e2 in sorted(enumerate(express), reverse=True):
        if e1 != e2: # checks that it isn't comparing against itself as a string
            if eval(e1) == eval(e2):
                express.pop(n)
```

`eval()` predictably evaluates the value of any expression in a string literal. Adding the above should check every expression in the `express` list and checks it against every other expression.

About using the reversed, enumerated lists: it's a method that allows you to remove elements from a list during iteration of the list. `enumerate()`ing it gives you the index of the item in the original list before `sorted(reverse=True)`ing it. You reverse it so that if an item is removed from the original list, the index of all the items *before* it is not affected.

Edits: clarification and markup